# Kendo UI Splitter: Change Splitbar color while splitter pane is resizing

Tags: javascript, css, kendo-ui

I recently started to work with KendoUI Splitter.

I have a white background and when I move the splitter handle to resize a pane, the split handle that shows the resize position of panes appears. the problem is, because the page background is white, I can barely see this handle so I want to change its color to more visible one.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="example" class="k-content">
        <div id="vertical">
            <div>
                <p>
                    Outer splitter : top pane (resizable and collapsible)
                </p>
            </div>
            <div id="middlePane">
                <div id="horizontal" style="height: 100%">
                    <div>
                        <p>
                            Inner splitter :: left pane
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <p>
                            Inner splitter :: center pane
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <p>
                            Inner splitter :: right pane
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>
                    Outer splitter : bottom pane (non-resizable, non-collapsible)
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**JS:**

```
$("#vertical").kendoSplitter({
    orientation: "vertical",
    panes: [
        { collapsible: false, resizable: false, size: "100px" },
        { collapsible: false },
        { collapsible: false, resizable: false, size: "100px" }
    ]
});

$("#horizontal").kendoSplitter({
    panes: [
       { collapsible: true },
       { collapsible: false },
       { collapsible: true }
    ]
});

$(window).resize(function() {
   resizeSplitter()
});

resizeSplitter = function() {
   splitter = $("#vertical")
    .data("kendoSplitter")
    .size("#middlePane", $(window).height() - 200 + "px")
    .trigger("resize")
};

resizeSplitter();
```

this is the [Splitter](http://jsfiddle.net/hsh85/fosxumcb/80/) in JSFiddle. I want to change the color of  splitbar while its moving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When resizing the splitter, a new element is added for the 'moving-splitbar'.
This element has a class of `.k-ghost-splitbar`, so you can add a custom background-color to that element.

```
.k-ghost-splitbar {
    background-color: red;
}
```

I've updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fosxumcb/81/).

Comment: Tnx a lot I was looking for this